# Zurb Foundation 6 using grid-column-row mixin

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm getting some strange behavior and was wondering if I am using a `grid-column-row` incorrectly.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="homeTop">
  <!-- homeTop content such as headings and other nested rows and columns -->
</div>
<div id="homeMain">
  <div id="homeMain-left"></div>
  <div id="homeMain-right"></div>
</div>
<div id="homeBottom">
  <!-- homeBottom content such as headings and other nested rows and columns -->
</div>
```

I then have the following SCSS to style this content:

```
#homeTop {
  @include grid-column-row;
}

#homeMain {
  @include grid-row;
}

#homeMain-left {
  @include grid-column(12);

  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    @include grid-column(8/12);
  }
}

#homeMain-right {
  @include grid-column(12);

  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    @include grid-column(4/12);
  }
}

#homeBottom {
  @include grid-column-row;
}
```

When I view the page on a desktop-sized screen, there is one line of css that's causing the `homeBottom` div to float right, which is throwing off the layout. The line of CSS causing the issue is here:

```
#homeBottom:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  float: right;
}
```

Since a `column-row` is meant to be a single element acting as a row and a column, in other words, a full width container, I'm confused why I would ever want it to have a float property. It seems that this line of CSS makes sense for `columns`, but not for `column-rows`, since the `column-row` behavior shouldn't depend on whether or not it's the `last-child` of its parent.

Is this a bug, or am I using the `column-row` incorrectly? I'm just trying to avoid setting `homeBottom` as a `grid-row`, and then including an extra html element inside of it just to act as a full-width `grid-column`. As you can see, this isn't necessary for `homeTop`, even though it's also using the `grid-column-row` mixin. This makes me think I may be using it incorrectly.

I guess another option would be to define my own `my-grid-column-row` mixin that includes the float declaration:

```
@mixin my-grid-column-row {
  @include grid-column-row;
  float: none !important;
}
```

But this seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with foundation:

http://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8108

My workaround for now is to override the `grid-column-row` mixin with the following:

```
@mixin grid-column-row(
  $gutter: $grid-column-gutter
) {
  @include grid-row;
  @include grid-column($gutter: $gutter);
  float: none !important;
}
```